# Unity doesnt work after activating the sky cube in CSSM

Tags: unity, compiz

I was trying to activate the sky cube in compiz.

Closed the program and rebooted now I only get the desktop screen with no icons.  I can't seem to be able to get anywhere with hot keys either.  Nothing seems to be working.

Tried to reboot in safe mode but the command line always indicates some sort of error and the repairs stop.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into your desktop as you normally would. Press ctrl+alt+f1 and log in using your account credentials. Now execute:

```
DISPLAY=:0 unity --reset
```

Return to your GUI by pressing ctrl+alt+f7. Everything should be back in place now. Reboot your computer to make the changes persistent.